# android:drawableEnd + setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds doesn't work

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have the following XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trickslist_childview_trick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/starone"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/starone"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/level"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

when I call `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` on it the changes are not set. Removing the `android:drawableEnd` attribute it works.

Is it a Bug?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's weird bug on Android Iced cream sandwich